# Python: Error saving output into csv file?

Tags: python, csv, file-io, save, delimiter

I realized this error only when open with MS Excel but it is just fine when open using Notepad++. The values are not in corresponding columns when I open using Excel. I have this following code which help me to do multiplication only according to value 1 in binary.csv and outputting values excluding all the 0 values in binary.csv. Can anyone help me?

**binary.csv**

```
0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0
```

**real.csv**

```
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.3
```

**Code**

```
import csv

with open('real.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        reals = row

with open('binary.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    pwreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    with open('onehothot.csv','wb') as testfile:
        csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
        for row in pwreader:
            result = []

            for i,b in enumerate(row):
                if b == '1' :
                    result.append(reals[i])

            c= ",".join(result)
            print(c)
            csv_writer.writerow([c])
```

**Output in csv file open using Notepad++**

```
0.2,0.5,0.3
0.1,0.5,0.6
0.4,0.5,0.3
```

**Desired output in csv file open using MS Excel (in 3 rows and 3 columns filled)**

```
0.2 0.5 0.3
0.1 0.5 0.6
0.4 0.5 0.3
```

The actual CSV output file I open using MS Excel is in 3 rows and 1 column filled because '0.2 0.5 0.3' is treated as single entity. Therefore only 3 entities displayed in Excel.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your output. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: The output is fine. Just that when open with MS Excel, the answer are in 3 columns instead of 9 columns. I would like to have it in 9 columns Excel.

Comment: But the output you show has three columns, so it's not surprising there are three columns in Excel. How could there be more?

Comment: Is there anything I can add on to split them?

Comment: So basically the output you show above is not the output you want. Edit the question showing the output your want which produces what you want in Excel. You might be able to create this by editing in excel and saving to csv, for example.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating `c`, the `csv` library will do this for you, i.e. `csv_writer.writerow(result)` is all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you. It solved perfectly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to try and create each column by joining with `,` as the `csv` library will do this for you, instead code it as follows:

```
import csv

with open('real.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        reals = row

with open('binary.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    pwreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    with open('onehothot.csv','wb') as testfile:
        csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
        for row in pwreader:
            result = []

            for i,b in enumerate(row):
                if b == '1' :
                    result.append(reals[i])

            csv_writer.writerow(result)
```